# WCSession activated successfully but session.isReachabilty always return false

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, watchos, watchconnectivity

******** Session Activated ******

Watch is paired true

Watch is reachable false

Watch app installed false

I have established the session but not able to make connection reachability between the iOS app (UIKit) and watchOS app (swiftUI)

**This is my watchConnectivity class**

```
import WatchConnectivity

class WatchSessionManager: NSObject, WCSessionDelegate {

    static let sharedManager = WatchSessionManager()
    public var watchDelegate: WCSessionDelegate?
    
    
    private override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    private let session: WCSession? = WCSession.isSupported() ? WCSession.default : nil


    @available(iOS 9.3, *)
    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        
        
        switch activationState {
               case .activated:
                   print("WCSession activated successfully")
               case .inactive:
                   print("Unable to activate the WCSession. Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "--")")
               case .notActivated:
                   print("Unexpected .notActivated state received after trying to activate the WCSession")
               @unknown default:
                   print("Unexpected state received after trying to activate the WCSession")
               }
                
        
        // Handle activation completion
        print("jew")
        if session.isReachable {
            let message = ["message": "Hello from iPhone"]
            session.sendMessage(message, replyHandler: nil) { (error) in
               print(error)
            }
        }else{
            print("Not Reachable")
        }
        
        
        
    #if os(iOS)
        print("******** Session Activated ******")
        print("Watch is paired \(session.isPaired)")
        print("Watch is reachable \(session.isReachable)")
        print("Watch app installed \(session.isWatchAppInstalled)")
    #endif
        //print("Watch is reachable \(session.isReachable)")
    }

    #if os(iOS)
    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("Session Inactive")
    }

    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
        print("Session deactivated")
    }
    #endif

    var validSession: WCSession? {

        // paired - the user has to have their device paired to the watch
        // watchAppInstalled - the user must have your watch app installed
        // Note: if the device is paired, but your watch app is not installed
        // consider prompting the user to install it for a better experience
        #if os(iOS)
            if let session = session, session.isPaired && session.isWatchAppInstalled {
                print("Watch is paired \(session.isPaired)")
                print("Watch app installed \(session.isWatchAppInstalled)")
                return session
            }
        #elseif os(watchOS)
        print("Watch is reachable \(session!.isReachable)")
            return session
        #endif
        
        return nil
    }

    func startSession() {
        session?.delegate = self
        session?.activate()
    }
}

// MARK: Application Context
// use when your app needs only the latest information
// if the data was not sent, it will be replaced
extension WatchSessionManager {

    // Sender
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {
            guard let content = message["content"] as? String else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //self.messageLabel.text = content
                print(content)
            }
        }
    
    func updateApplicationContext(applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) throws {
        
        if let session = validSession {
            do {
                print("WCSession contect sent \(applicationContext)")
                try session.updateApplicationContext(applicationContext)
                print("WCSession contect sent \(applicationContext)")
            } catch let error {
                throw error
            }
        }else{
            print("Error sending context")
        }
       
    }

    // Receiver
//    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : Any]) {
//        // handle receiving application context
//        let isEnabledStatus = applicationContext["isEnabled"] as? Bool
//
//       // DispatchQueue.main.async {
//        print("Received application context \(applicationContext) 1")
//            #if os(watchOS)
//            if watchDelegate != nil{
//                print("Received application context \(applicationContext) 2")
//
//            }
//            #endif
//            // make sure to put on the main queue to update UI!
//       // }
//    }
}

// MARK: User Info
// use when your app needs all the data
// FIFO queue
extension WatchSessionManager {

    // Sender
    func transferUserInfo(userInfo: [String : AnyObject]) -> WCSessionUserInfoTransfer? {
        return validSession?.transferUserInfo(userInfo)
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didFinish userInfoTransfer: WCSessionUserInfoTransfer, error: Error?) {
        // implement this on the sender if you need to confirm that
        // the user info did in fact transfer
    }

    // Receiver
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : Any] = [:]) {
        // handle receiving user info
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // make sure to put on the main queue to update UI!
        }
    }

}

// MARK: Transfer File
extension WatchSessionManager {

    // Sender
    func transferFile(file: NSURL, metadata: [String : AnyObject]) -> WCSessionFileTransfer? {
        return validSession?.transferFile(file as URL, metadata: metadata)
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didFinish fileTransfer: WCSessionFileTransfer, error: Error?) {
        // handle filed transfer completion
    }

    // Receiver
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceive file: WCSessionFile) {
        // handle receiving file
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // make sure to put on the main queue to update UI!
        }
    }
}


// MARK: Interactive Messaging
extension WatchSessionManager {

    // Live messaging! App has to be reachable
    private var validReachableSession: WCSession? {
        if let session = validSession , session.isReachable {
            return session
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    // Sender
    func sendMessage(message: [String : AnyObject],
                     replyHandler: (([String : Any]) -> Void)? = nil,
                     errorHandler: ((Error) -> Void)? = nil)
    {
        validReachableSession?.sendMessage(message, replyHandler: replyHandler, errorHandler: errorHandler)
        
    }

    func sendMessageData(data: Data,
                         replyHandler: ((Data) -> Void)? = nil,
                         errorHandler: ((Error) -> Void)? = nil)
    {
        validReachableSession?.sendMessageData(data, replyHandler: replyHandler, errorHandler: errorHandler)
    }

    // Receiver
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void) {
        // handle receiving message
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // make sure to put on the main queue to update UI!
            print("Message Received\(message)")
            
        }
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessageData messageData: Data) {
        // handle receiving message data
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            // make sure to put on the main queue to update UI!
        }
    }
}
```

in ios setting in appdelegate:

```
 WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.startSession() in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
```

in watchOS

```
.onAppear {
                WatchSessionManager.sharedManager.startSession()
            }
```

I tried to pass the data between my iOS app and watchOS app

```
private func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : String]) -> Void) {
           replyHandler(["message": "Hello Watch!"])
       }
```

Comment: Are you using iPhone and Apple Watch simulators or a pair of real devices?

Comment: No, I'm using actual real devices not simulators